# scan a folder with a date passed as a parameter

Tags: shell

How can i do a shell script for do this:
The call of the script will see the "/DataFolder" to list all files *.INI with the date passed as a parameter.
The result should if possible retain only the file name and time the file was changed and the list must be sorted in ascending order.
If no parameter is passed, we take the current date

Thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using `find` for this:

```
find /DataFolder -type f -iname '*.ini*'  \
  -mtime +MINIMUM_DAYS_SINCE_MODIFICATION \
  -printf "%TY%Tm%Td %f\n"                \
| sort -n
```

This outputs modification time with YEAR MONTH DAY concatenated and thus can be piped directly info `sort`.